# what is the correct laravel syntax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

while working with form in laravel blade this syntax works

```
{!!Form::token()!!} //with double exclamation mark
```

for including a remote js file this works

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/register.js')}}" ></script>
```

with no exclamation mark.In fact exclamation mark created problem .js file was not found error.

I want to know the difference of the two syntax .and when to use which one ?

Answer (score 15):

From Laravel's documentation:

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want
>   your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>
> Hello, {!! $name !!}.
>
> ```
> Note: Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application. Always use the double curly brace syntax to escape any HTML entities in the content.
> ```

Using `{{ $var }}` will be equivalent to `<?php echo htmlentities($var);?>`

Using `{!! $var !!}}` is equivalent to `<?php echo $var;?>`

Generally speaking, you'd use `{{ }}` most of the time, unless there are special characters which are not showing since `htmlentities` is escaping them. Only in these cases you'd use `{!! !!}}`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: then why {!! asset('js/register.js') !!} could not include the file?

Comment: Look into the browser developer tools (or view the source of the document) and see what is the actual path that is being used

Comment: where does that 'note' come from in your answer, looks like it comes from the laravel documentation.